# VS 2012 sqlite design time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, visual-studio-2012

So now **1.0.83.0** just got released I thought I would be able to work on a project again that requires a **SQLite** model (edmx file, EF).
So I downloaded the  **sqlite-netFx45-setup-bundle-x86-2012-1.0.83.0.exe** from [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) ("This setup package is capable of installing the design-time components for **Visual Studio 2012**.").
So I installed it and I checked the checkboxes were it said: "Integrate into VS 2012". Now when I start VS 2012 (even after a restart). When I select add new Entity thingie to my project and I have to say `New connection" -> Select Data source`. There is MS SQL server, SQL server compact etc but no sqlite! Anyone know what I should do to get this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I could not get System.Data.SQLite v.1.0.83.0 design-time to work in VS2012 either and I ended up using devart like this person's (user676797) answer posted two days ago.
[Is SQLite working with VS 2012 and .NET 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291423/sqlite-with-visual-studio-2012-and-net-4-5?rq=1)

I found the free version (devart.com "dotconnect for SQLite") was easy to install and worked on the first try. I spent many hours trying to get anything from System.Data.SQLite to work and never could.