# Is it possible to use the Entity Framework designer with SQLite in VS2012?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sqlite, visual-studio-2012

I've looked around and [seen entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111505/vs-2012-sqlite-design-time) that state it should be possible and it should be available anytime now.  I've downloaded many different releases (their website contains a metric ton of them) - all to no avail.  What I can't find is a definitive statement whether the designer exists and if it does what download it's included with.

So, does a SQLite Entity Framework designer that works with Visual Studio 2012 exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does exist. Download from here:

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Remember to select the 32-bit installation package that says: "This setup package is capable of installing the design-time components for Visual Studio 2012.".